# Twilio update resource async after previous verb has completed

Tags: twilio, sleep, twilio-api, thread-sleep, twilio-functions

How do I stop the async update call from completely interrupting the call? I would like `response.Say("Let me think about that.")` to finish before the async call is made, currently it just stops the `Say()` verb mid sentence.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Intermediate(string RecordingUrl)
    {
        recordingUrl = RecordingUrl;
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("Let me think about that.");
        //Asynchronously POST
        var call = CallResource.UpdateAsync(
            method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
            url: new Uri("http://123456789/voice/show"),
            pathSid: sessionIdentifier, fallbackUrl: new Uri("http://123456789/voice/Fallback"));
        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than updating the call with a request to the API, why not just use the [`<Redirect>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/redirect). You could achieve your redirect after the `<Say>` with:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Intermediate(string RecordingUrl)
{
    recordingUrl = RecordingUrl;
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    response.Say("Let me think about that.");
    response.Redirect(new Uri("http://123456789/voice/show"));
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.